# Logstash + SQS startup error

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

Am using `Logstash` with file-based inputs & `AWS SQS` as output. The output logstash config is as follows:

```
output {
 sqs {
    queue => "my-queue"
    access_key_id => "xxx"
    secret_access_key => "xyz"
    region  => "us-east-1"
 }
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

& I see the below error upon starting Logstash:

```
Unable to access SQS queue 'my-queue': The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/

content-length:95
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
host:sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-sdk-ruby/1.65.0 jruby/1.9.3 java
x-amz-content-sha256:4fcf205bdb6d3a91a4c2e3543e6720c8d13b16e8070e7c9bca7e56147fb0b513
x-amz-date:20150908T191848Z

content-length;content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
4fcf205bdb6d3a91a4c2e3543e6720c8d13b16e8070e7c9bca7e56147fb0b513'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20150908T191848Z
20150908/us-east-1/sqs/aws4_request
8a2c2e7b807cefb1f95207a3c700c89ead7796428d39bfb7445d6adc9cbf81b9'
{:level=>:error}
```

Would highly appreciate if anyone can throw more light on this.

Comment: so `aws api access key` is wrong, did you set properly?

Comment: You are not the only one who has the problem:

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-sqs/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the right `AWS Credentials` I would create a new `access key` just to be sure.